# laravel 9 controller/view still in cache even after cleanup

Tags: php, laravel

After uploading the files to the production server, I was getting the old view/data. I have modified the file ServerController.php directly on the server (added a database update call to a place where I was sure the code will be executed). The update did not execute. At that time I thought about cache issue, so I ran following commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

No change. I have even deleted the file ServerController.php from the disk and I still get an old response instead of 404 error. I've also tried different browsers and incognito mode. The result is always the same. I have verified that the directories storage/framework/views and storage/framework/cache/data are actually empty after clearing the caches. There are no web server caches on the server as far as I am aware. Any ideas?

Comment: and who is your host? sounds like an issue with your host's caching perhaps

Comment: It was an Apache issue. It works after restarting. Funny thing is, it only happens to that particular controller.

Answer (score -1):

it might be server-side cache
if your hosting using hostinger try this :

1. Log in to your Hostinger account.
2. On the hPanel homepage, click the Hosting tab.
3. Find the domain in question and click the Manage button.
4. Scroll down to Advanced → Cache Manager.
5. Enable caching by clicking the Automatic cache toggle. If it is already on, proceed to the next step.
6. Click the Purge all button to clear your account’s cache completely. Optionally, enter a URL into the field and select Purge to remove specific data.

if not try to contact your hosting provider